# haystack more_like_this returns object of different class

Tags: django, django-haystack, morelikethis

I expect to get list of `Article` objects when I call `SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(an_article)`

However it returns objects of other classes as well.

What could I possibly miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this yet myself but you should be able to restrict it to certain models like this.

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Article).more_like_this(an_article)
```

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#models